# how to get radio button names based on value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, radio-button

I am building a survey system. I have a page containing 10 items, each item has yes/no options to select. Something like this:

```
    Yes   No
1.   o    o
2.   o    o
...

<submit>
```

When I hit submit button, I want to know which items have been selected to yes and no. How can I do that? Thanks.

I know how to retrieve radio button value by name, my question is how to get buttons whose selected value is "yes" and "no". I kinda know how to do it in javascript, but I am not sure how to pass the javascript value back to the PHP script.

Comment: You have to be collecting the data with either `$_GET[]` or `$_POST[]`, right? Just manipulate that data how you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like this

```
<input type="radio" value="1'"name="radbut">Yes
<input type="radio" value="2" name="radbut">No
```

the php to select the selected value is like this

```
$selected=$_GET["radbut"];
```

Comment: `$selected` would then hold an array of all the values, correct?

Comment: it should get only selected button because it based on name

Answer (score 0):

I will go into a detailed explanation.

```
<input type="radio" name="option1" value="Yes"> Yes
<input type="radio" name="option1" value="No"> No
```

When you're processing this via PHP, there will only be a single "option1" posted value. It will either be Yes, or No, based on which input the user selected.

```
echo "The user selected: ".$_POST['option1'];
```

If yes, the above will return:

> The user selected: Yes

Same goes for the No.

Comment: Why not use arrays - `<input name="option[1]" `?